# wchar_t vs char for creating an API

Tags: c, winapi

I am creating a C++ library meant to be used with different applications written in different languages like Java, C#, Delphi etc.

Every now and then I am stuck on conversions between wstrings, strings, char*, wchar_t*. E.g. I sticked to wchar_t's but had to use regex library which accepts chars other similar problems.

I wish to stick to either w's or normal strings. My library will mostly deal with ASCII characters but can have non-ASCII characters too as in names etc. So, can I permanently switch to char's instead of wchar_t's and string's instead of wstring's. Can I have unicode  support with them and will it affect scalability and portability across different platforms and languages.

Please advise.

Comment: @bames53 can you please advise me on this issue

Comment: just use normal char's. if people want to use wide characters they can just use utf8(full unicode support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide which encoding to use. Some considerations:

- If you can have non-ASCII characters, then there is no point in choosing ASCII or 8bit ANSI. That way leads to disappointment and risks data loss.
- It makes sense to pick one encoding and stick to it. Everywhere. The Windows API is unusual in supporting both ANSI and Unicode, but that is due to backwards compatibility of old software. If Microsoft were starting over from scratch, there would be one encoding only.
- The most common choices for Unicode encoding are UTF-8 and UTF-16. Any decent environment will have support for both. Either choice may be justifiable.
- Java, VB, C# and Delphi all have good support for UTF-16, and all of them use UTF-16 for their native string types (in the case of Delphi, the native string type is UTF-16 only in Delphi 2009 and later.  For earlier versions, you can use the `WideString` string type).
- Most OS platforms are natively UTF-16 (*Nix systems, like Linux, are UTF-8 instead), so it may well be simplest to just use UTF-16.
- On the other hand, UTF-8 is probably a technically better choice being byte oriented, and backwards compatible with 8bit ASCII. Quite likely, if Unicode was being invented from scratch, there would be no UTF-16 and UTF-8 would be the variable length encoding.

You have phrased the question as a choice between `char` and `wchar_t`. I think that the real choice is what your preferred encoding should be.  You also have to watch out that `wchar_t` is 16bit (UTF-16) on some systems but is 32bit (UTF-32) on others.  It is not a portable data type.  That is why C++11 introduces new `char16_t` and char32_t` data types to correct that ambiguity.

Comment: How can I set the encoding. I mean can I use char* with UTF-8 encoding

Comment: That depends. If your code compiles on a system with 16 bit char then you cannot use `char*` to hold UTF-8 data. But such systems are unusual. I think that it is pretty common to use `char*` to hold UTF-8 payloads. But you don't just "set the encoding". You'll need a fair amount of library support. And it's really no fun in C which leaves you hanging out to dry, all alone in the internationalization wilderness. Even C++ isn't all that much better.

Comment: I am bit confused, my library targets Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8 and will be compiled on a Windows 7 machine. Is there any declaration to be made in the header file to enable utf-8 for char strings.

Comment: No, nothing as simple as that. If you only target Windows then UTF-16 will be simpler.

Comment: I assume that by utf-16 you mean wstring and wchar_t

Comment: @adnankamili `wchar_t` isn't always UTF-16 it can be UTF-32 (linux and mac) as well

Comment: By UTF-16 I mean the Unicode text encoding that is defined by the Unicode standard. On Windows you typically use `wchar_t` to hold UTF-16 character elements. But that doesn't work on a platform with 32 bit wide characters. `wstring` is no good to you because you code in C rather than C++. Judging from your comments, you really do need to step back and learn about Unicode. You cannot take such decisions until you know more.

Comment: @Mgetz it's more about the width of the type than the text encoding. For instance a char can hold text with many different encodings. The point is that wide characters on *nix platforms tend to be 32 bits wide rather than being tied to a specific encoding.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am using c++ too inside the library (non-API helper functions), the API has C style functions only.

Comment: That makes it a C++ library with a procedural external interface. The question is mis-tagged in my view. C++ would be a better tag.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I use char, so by default it will be unicode, but almost all winapi functions accept wchar_t arguments, e.g registry writing functions which has an A variant which assumes ASCII.

Comment: You don't have a strong enough understanding of any of these issues yet. You need to step back and gain that understanding. Step 1, get a firm understanding Unicode and it's primary encodings, UTF-8/16/32.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you could point to some direction, besides I meant utf-8 in the previous comment and not unicode

Comment: On windows char usually means ANSI. There are countless good articles and books on Unicode. Surely you can search.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan does the windows API actually support UTF-16 properly or does it just do UCS-2 ?  (The difference is felt for non-BMP characters).

Comment: @Matt Yes, Win api supports utf16

Comment: OK so functions like SysStringLen will give the number of letters in the string? (as opposed to number of wchar_t's) ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb No, that will give the number of `wchar_t` elements.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference between Unicode and simple char is code page. Having just a `char*` pointer is not enough to understand the meaning of the string. It can be in a certain specific encoding, it can be multibyte, etc. Wide character string does not have these caveats.

In many cases international aspects are not important. In this case the difference between these 2 representations is minimal. The main question that you need to answer: is internationalization  important to your library or not?

Answer (score 1):

Modern Windows programming should tend towards builds with `UNICODE` defined, and thus use wide characters and wide character APIs. This is desirable for improved performance (fewer or no conversions behind the Windows API layers), improved capabilities (sometimes the ANSI wrappers don't expose all capabilities of the wide function), and in general it avoids problems with the inability to represent characters that are not on the system's current code page (and thus in practice the inability to represent non-ASCII characters).

Where this can be difficult is when you have to interface with things that don't use wide characters. For example, while Windows APIs have wide character filenames, Linux filesystems typically use bytestrings. While those bytestrings are often UTF-8 by convention, there's little enforcement. Interfacing with other languages can also be difficult if the language in question doesn't understand wide characters at an API level. Ideally such languages have chosen a specific encoding, such as UTF-8, allowing you to convert to and from that encoding at the boundaries.

And that's one general recommendation: use Unicode internally for all processing, and convert as necessary at the boundaries. If this isn't already familiar to you, it's good to reference [Joel's article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).